# Pass a JS boolean when changing text in a input field?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

How do I pass a JS boolean to hidden CFINPUT field when a user has edited text in a specific input text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say this is your field

```
<input type="text" id="textbox1" value="abc def" name="somename1" onchange="passToHiddenField()" />
```

And this is your hidden input field

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden1" name="somename2" value="" />
```

Then add the script function

```
<script>
function passToHiddenField(){
     document.getElementById('hidden1').value = 1; //do whatever you want in this function.
}
</script>
```

Comment: The value of the hidden field would always be 1 then?

Comment: That's not that. The main thing I want to mention here is we can pass 1 (true) to the hidden field whenever the user edited the `#textbox1`. That why I comment on the function that we can do whatever we want in that function. You can see that the default value of `#hidden1` is nothing (false).

Comment: Hi Bang Dao,

I added all the fields like you mentioned above but the hidden input seems to stay empty. Here are the Scope Variables after making a change in the email field and submitting:

Form Fields:
PHONE_NUMBER=999-999-9999
SOMENAME2=

Here is my hidden field and email input:
<input type="hidden" id="hidden1" name="somename2" value="" />
Email Address:&nbsp;<input style="width: 100px;" name="EMAIL_ADDRESS" type="text" maxlength="40" value="<cfoutput>#EMAIL_ADDRESS#</cfoutput>" onchange="passToHiddenField()" />

The JS call is in the top portion of the page.

Why is it not submit value 1?

Comment: Hi, I tested by myself and found nothing wrong in my code. Then it must be wrong somewhere else. Did you insert the js function to your page, the **passToHiddenField** function?